# How can i track if text in editText is changed without using textWatcher?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can i track if text in editText is changed without using textWatcher?Pls help..

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use textWatcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check in key listener event of the EditText

```
et.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
           isEdit = true;
           return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
});
```

but like this was it's too complex, I suggest you to preffer textwatcher for tracking